# MySQL Dynamic Optimization with variable AND OR NOT operators

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, dynamic-sql

UPDATE - FINAL SOLUTION TO THIS ISSUE

Our dynamic system allows for a BOOLEAN interpolated match of things like Name, Job Title, Phone Number, etc. So we can say:

Name("ted" OR "mike" OR "david" AND "martin") AND Title("developer" AND "senior" NOT "CTO) AND City("san diego")

The way this is accomplished is to follow the below grouping example, which is dynamically created. It's pretty straightforward, however the use of HAVING COUNT is necessary to properly define the AND indexes.

Also not in this example access_indexes is a list of ID indexes an account has access to, so if the "search" returns a person the account can't access, it won't show up.

Thanks to everyone for your help, especially @BillKarwin!

```
WITH filter0 AS
(
    SELECT pm.ID FROM person_main pm
    WHERE MATCH(pm.name_full) AGAINST ('(ted)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
), 
filter1 AS
(
    SELECT ram.object_ref_id AS ID
    FROM ras_assignment_main ram
    WHERE ram.object_type_c = 1
        AND ram.assignment_type_c = 1
        AND ram.assignment_ref_id IN (2)
), 
persongroup0_and AS 
( 

    SELECT pg0_a.ID FROM
    (
        SELECT ID FROM filter0            
    ) pg0_a
    GROUP BY pg0_a.ID
    HAVING COUNT(pg0_a.ID) = 1
),
persongroup0 AS 
(
    SELECT pm.ID
    FROM person_main pm 
    JOIN persongroup0_and pg0_and ON pm.ID = pg0_and.ID 
),
persongroup1_and AS 
( 
    SELECT pg1_a.ID FROM
    (
        SELECT ID FROM filter1            
    ) pg1_a
    GROUP BY pg1_a.ID
    HAVING COUNT(pg1_a.ID) = 1
),  
persongroup1 AS 
(
    SELECT pm.ID
    FROM person_main pm 
    JOIN persongroup1_and pg1_and ON pm.ID = pg1_and.ID
),  
person_all_and AS 
(     
    SELECT paa.ID FROM
    (
        SELECT ID FROM persongroup0 
        UNION ALL (SELECT ID FROM persongroup1)             
    ) paa
    GROUP BY paa.ID
    HAVING COUNT(paa.ID) = 2
), 
person_all AS 
(
    SELECT pm.ID
    FROM person_main pm 
    JOIN person_all_and pa_and ON pm.ID = pa_and.ID 
),
person_access AS
(
    SELECT pa.ID
    FROM person_all pa
    LEFT JOIN access_indexes ai ON pa.ID = ai.ID
)
SELECT (JSON_ARRAYAGG(pm.ID))
FROM 
(        
    SELECT person_sort.ID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT pa.ID
        FROM person_access pa
        GROUP BY pa.ID
    ) person_sort    
) pm;
```

---

Our front-end system has the ability to define dynamic SQL queries using AND/OR/NOT from multiple tables, and the core system works fine - but it's slows down to being unusable due to the compounded scanning of IN. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to have this level of dynamic functionality without using IN. Below is the code that works perfectly fine (the filter matching is ultra fast), but the compounding of the IN scan takes > 60 seconds because it's 50,000+ records for some of the filter returns.

```
        WITH filter0 AS
        (
            SELECT pm.ID FROM person_main pm
            WHERE MATCH(pm.name_full) AGAINST ('mike meyers' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        ), 
        filter1 AS
        (
            SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
            FROM person_history_work phw
            WHERE MATCH(phw.work_title) AGAINST('developer' IN BOOLEAN MODE)                
        ), 
        filter2 AS
        (
            SELECT pa.person_main_ref_id AS ID
            FROM person_address pa
            WHERE pa.global_address_details_ref_id IN
            (
                SELECT gad.ID
                FROM global_address_details gad
                WHERE gad.address_city LIKE '%seattle%'
            )
        ),        
        all_indexes AS
        (         
            SELECT ID FROM filter0
            UNION (SELECT ID FROM filter1)
            UNION (SELECT ID FROM filter2)
        ),         
        person_filter AS
        (
            SELECT ai.ID
            FROM all_indexes ai
            WHERE 
            ( 
                ai.ID IN            (SELECT ID FROM filter0) 
                AND ai.ID NOT IN    (SELECT ID FROM filter1) 
                OR ai.ID IN         (SELECT ID FROM filter2)
            ) 
        )
         
        SELECT (JSON_ARRAYAGG(pf.ID)) FROM person_filter pf;
```

Filter 0 has 461 records, Filter 1 has 48480 and Filter 2 has 750.

The key issue is with the WHERE statement; because the front-end can say AND/OR and NOT on any "joined" query.

So if I change it to:

```
                ai.ID IN      (SELECT ID FROM filter0) 
                AND ai.ID IN  (SELECT ID FROM filter1) 
                AND ai.ID IN  (SELECT ID FROM filter2)
```

The query takes more than 60 seconds. Because it's scanning 461 * 48480 * 750 = 16,761,960,00. UGH.

Of course I could hardcode around this if it was a static stored procedure or call, but it's a dynamic interpolative system that takes the settings defined by the user, so the user can define the above.

As you can see what I do is create a list of all indexes involved, then select them based on the AND/OR/NOT values as defined by the front-end web tool.

Obviously IN won't work for this; the question is what other techniques could I use that don't involve the use of IN that would allow the same level of flexibility with AND/OR/NOT?

---

Update for @BillKarwin in Comments

So the below code works well for executing an AND, NOT and OR:

```
            SELECT pm.ID
            FROM person_main pm
            JOIN filter0 f0 ON f0.ID = pm.ID -- AND
            LEFT JOIN filter1 f1 ON pm.ID = f1.ID WHERE f1.ID IS NULL -- NOT
            UNION (SELECT ID FROM filter2) -- OR
```

I believe I can make this work with our system; I just need to store the different types (AND/NOT/OR) and execute them in process; let me do some updates and I'll get back to you.

Comment: It's hard to say because we don't know what the range of possibilities are for your user-defined conditions. But in general, I recommend using `JOIN` as a way to implement the `AND` conditions. Then you can use UNION for the `OR` conditions.

Comment: But ultimately, it's practically impossible to optimize all possible dynamic queries that users come up with.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes, but what about NOT? That's the core issue; I wish we had a way to nullify values from a UNION of single IDs (I think MSSQL has EXCEPT or something) but I can't see a dynamic way to implement that.

Comment: Correct, MySQL supports UNION, but [does not yet support the other operations EXCEPT or INTERSECT](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1309). There are ways to simulate except using an outer join. The technique is called an exclusion join. Example: https://www.urgenthomework.com/sql-left-excluding-join-homework-help

Comment: @BillKarwin gotcha thanks - that does work - but as you mentioned above, matching all of the dynamic combinations with AND/OR/NOT seems impossible - especially with nested groups and without very specific restrictions. For example if they do AND/NOT/OR that alone cannot be processed per UNION, JOIN, or LEFT JOIN (EXCEPT) in order received; a type of interpreter would have to be written to properly order the queries, and with grouping that creating a mess of management. Curious what limitations do you recommend putting on the front-end query engine?

Comment: Only as much as you can build support for in your query engine. If you can optimize `AND`-type expressions, then give them that choice. As you build ways to optimize other types of expressions, give them additional choices. Then a final choice: "anything else you want, but it'll be very slow."

Comment: @BillKarwin updated the main task with a note. I'm going to dig into this and see if I can make it work. So we have JOIN (AND), LEFT JOIN (AND NOT), and UNION (OR). But how do we include OR NOT in the JOIN>LEFT JOIN>UNION order of process?

Comment: I think OR NOT would be UNION, with the rows that do not match the condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247207/discussion-between-floobinator-and-bill-karwin).

Comment: @BillKarwin I sent you private chat. Sadly, it's not working; doing a JOIN with the same record counts results in the same delay/timing as IN does. Please check the private chat for details.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to enter a private chat. I am sure you will work on it and learn how to employ the various operations to the get result you want.

Comment: @BillKarwin your response of mocking AND/OR/NOT per JOIN, LEFT JOIN and UNION was the correct answer; but on top of that, it's critical that a UNION of each is performed so multiple JOINS (for example) aren't done, or it results in the same lag issue as IN. If you can please post an answer encapsulating this, I'll award the points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above:

Logically, you can replace a lot of your subqueries with JOIN when they are AND terms of your expression, or UNION when they are OR terms of your expression. Also learn about exclusion joins.

But that doesn't necessarily mean that the queries will run faster, unless you have created indexes to support the join conditions and the user-defined conditions.

But which indexes should you create?

Ultimately, it's not possible to optimize all dynamic queries that users come up with. You may be able to run their queries (as you are already doing), but they won't be efficient.

It's kind of a losing game to allow users to specify arbitrary conditions. It's better to give them a fixed set of choices, which are types of queries that you have taken the time to optimize. Then allow them to run a "user-specified" query, but label it clearly that it is not optimized and it will likely take a long time.

Comment: Original Post modified to show solution "style and technique".

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )`  -- Use `JOIN` or `EXISTS`

Avoid `SELECT ID FROM ( SELECT ID FROM .... )` -- The outer SELECT is unnecessary.

Move `UNION` to the outer level (in some situations)

`all_indexes` seems to simplify to

```
( SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
            FROM  person_history_work AS phw
            WHERE  MATCH(phw.work_title) AGAINST('developer' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
) UNION ALL
( SELECT gad.ID
      FROM  global_address_details AS gad
      WHERE  gad.address_city LIKE '%seattle%' 
)
```

Can you change the last part to `WHERE address_city = 'seattle'`?  If so, then you can use `INDEX(address_city)`  If not, would a FULLTEXT index together with MATCH work for you?

See if you can follow my lead and simplify the rest.

`WITH` was only recently added to the MySQL's syntax.  I suspect it will take another release or two before it is well optimized; try to avoid `WITH`.  Since you are "building" the query, you can "build" `UNION`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc, as needed.